# Jquery UI Dialog - Custom Close Button (X)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to set some custom functions for when I click the standard X button. I have scrolled through the API and all related information and it is completely barren when it comes to this. The documentation is shockingly poor and rather sub standard for such a commonly used piece of software.

What I want to do is when the X is clicked I would like it to run some custom code. Unfortunetely the X button lacks an id and there is no documentation on how to access it directly. I have seen answers on here suggesting users to create a "Close" button but that seems rather pointless as it already comes with one and further more I don't wish to have a close button located at the bottom of the window but in the title bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
  $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").click( function() {
     //some code
 });
```

Comment: +1, but be aware that this will still add the handler to all existing close buttons, which you said was undesirable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
beforeClose:function(e){
//do something here
}
});
```

Comment: I have multiple buttons that use the close feature, by using that method it effects all of them. I just want to give custom code specifically to that X/close button. For instance I have a minimize button that also uses the close method.